# table inside a jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to wrap a table in a jquery accordion like this...

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Room Flow</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>contained content</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output however is different. The accordion divs a re rendered above the table like this...

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Room Flow</h3>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>contained content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The tables are displayed via a partialview. The accordion divs are in the parent view. This is in an asp.net mvc razor project.

edit: I need to mention that when I remove the tables, the accordion works.

Comment: Are you positive that you aren't forgetting to close one/all of the DIVs in your actual code? Just a thought.

Comment: are you using script to do the wrapping, if so where is the script

Comment: I've removed each wrapping tag in the hierarchy one at a time until I got to the table, so I'm confident that's the issue. Replacing the table with other html fixes the issue. The wrapper is hard coded.

Comment: @EthanPelton  - have you solved this problem? I am facing same issue.. Can u plz help?

Comment: @vaishali - would you create a new question and post your code there? I'll try to answer there, but it will also attract other developers to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I was using extra wrapper while getting results. I will post code in some time.