# Including table elements in a partialview loaded on ajax callback

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a page that loads with some partial views. The user can insert items, which are represented by these partial views. The user clicks insert, the insert occurs and sends back the partial view which replaces the old html with the new.

The page loads correctly, and the data is inserted correctly, however, when the async callback comes through, all table elements - so tr and td - tags are striped out.

If I reload the page, the table elements and new data are displayed correctly. does this behavior sound familiar?

Its a bit difficult to show all the pieces of code that are involved here, but I'll try to condense it down to share. Just thought this scenario might ring a bell for someone.

This seems similar to another unanswered question I've posted...
[table inside a jquery accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932582/table-inside-a-jquery-accordion)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the table as runat="server"